# XCODE Swift Replacing HTTP-Get App-ID with a space

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

Sup dudes,
Working on creating a Bing Image Search API for Swift. My problem is that my app key contains '+' and '/' so when I make a request, I'm getting back because it seems that it treats '+' and '/' as spaces. It should treat everything before the query as a regular character, right?

Any idea how to fix this request so it doesn't screw up my AppID?

App ID Example:

```
"aaaaaa/aaaaaa+baaaaa/asdf="
```

Response (Formatting is off, but it is in fact a space between the a's)

```
{"SearchResponse":{"Version":"2.2","Query":{"SearchTerms":"sushi"},"Errors":
[{"Code":1002,"Message":"Parameter has invalid 
value.","Parameter":"SearchRequest.AppId","Value":"aaaaaa\u002faaaaaa 
baaaaa\u002fasdf\u003d","HelpUrl":"http\u003a\u002f\u002fmsdn.microsoft.com\u002fen-
us\u002flibrary\u002fdd251042.aspx"}]}}
```

Code for get request (works perfectly):

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?Appid="+AccountKey+"&query="+query+"&sources=Image");
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
     println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}        
task.resume()
```

Forgot to mention, I got frustrated and tried it out in C# and it works flawlessly. New to Swift (obviously)

Edit: Added URL string to Get Request code sample above.

Comment: Is the app key contained in the URL as a parameter, or is it in POST data?  If it is a URL parameter then you will need to percent encode the + & / characters

Comment: Sorry, got busy at work. I tried encoding it as '%2B' as I read on line and it comes back as a '/'. Have you ever tried do an HTTP get in Swift?

Comment: %2b is the right encoding for a "+".  Personally I am avoiding Swift as I don't see any benefits and a whole bunch of risk compared to the maturity of Objective C, but there shouldn't be anything that Swift does different as far as calling NSURLSession.  How are you creating `url` ?

Comment: At work right now, I'll look at my code when I get home and let you know. I really appreciate your help though, Paul. For me, coming from primarily a C#/Java background (with some C++) Swift is just easier for me to learn.

Comment: Paul, added in the changes. H